# Zend Studio 10: "Composer" contextual menu missing?

Tags: eclipse, macos, zend-framework, composer-php, zend-studio

I have installed Zend Studio 10, installed the Composer plug-in, created a ZF2 project and configured it with Composer. However, when I right click on the project in PHP Explorer, there is no contextual menu item for Composer. All of the tutorials that I've found on how to use Composer with Zend Studio 10 imply that there should be. I have seen other questions regarding this problem here and on the Zend forum and they all point to missing  in the .project file. However, I have checked and mine seems to be complete. Any suggestions?

```
<nature>org.zend.php.framework.ZendFrameworkNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</natur$
<nature>org.zend.php.zendserver.deployment.core.DeploymentNatur$
<nature>com.dubture.composer.core.composerNature</nature>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been playing with this for some time now and believe that the Zend documentation is in need of some updates. I have managed to find all of the Composer functionality in the main project view - a contextual menu does not seem to be required and, I suspect, has been removed as a result.